# Database Query Syntax

Tags: php, html, laravel

Solution: I used db facade, `DB::select()` to run raw sql query.

I have two tables users(id, username, city, country) and friends(id, user_id, friend_id, status). The 'users' table stores the user information and 'friends' table store the currently logged in user's id, friend_id is the id of the user who sent a friend request to the current user and status will be 'received'. I want to show information of the users to sent requests to the current user. Is my database query syntax correct? I can see correct output if I don't use the nested subquery. Thanks in advance!

My DB query:

```
$friendrequests = DB::table('users')->select(['username','city','country'])->where('id',DB::table('friends')->select('friend_id')->where([['status','received'],['user_id',$user->id]]));
```

My html:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Friend Requests
@endsection

@section('content')
    @include('includes.message-block')
    <section class="row requests">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <header><h3>Friend Requests</h3></header>
            <div class="requestlist">
                <header><h2>You have request from:</h2></header>
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <p>Name: {{ $user->username }}<br />City: {{ $user->city }}<br />Country:{{ $user->country }}</p>
                    <div class="interaction">
                        //stuff here
                    </div>
                @endforeach
                <a href="{{ URL::previous() }}">Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
```

The route:

```
Route::get('/friendrequests',[
        'uses' => 'FriendController@getFriendRequests',
        'as' => 'friendrequests',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);
```

The controller (works if I don't use the nested subquery):

```
public function getFriendRequests()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $friendrequests = DB::table('users')
        ->select(['username','city','country'])
        ->where('id',
            DB::table('friends')->select('friend_id')->where([['status','received'],['user_id',$user->id]])->get())->get();

        return view('friendrequests',['users' => $friendrequests]);
    }
```

Comment: so you are trying to say get me the user that his friends sent him request ?

Comment: I want to show John all the friend requests that he receives. The status attribute of the relation dictates whether two users are friends. The status can have one of the following values: sent, received, accepted, and blocked.

Comment: Don't edit the title to say it's solved. If someone answer solved it, mark it as correct (click on check icon on answer's left side). If you solved by yourself, help others posting the solution (yes, you can answer your own question)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with the approach of "hasManyThrough". In your User's model you should do something like this:

```php
class User extends Model{

  //... your code here

  public function possibleFriends(){
    $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Friend::class, 'friend_id', 'id')->wherePivot('status', 'received');
  }

}
```

More details in the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this may be helpful

```
$friendrequests = DB::table('users')
    ->select(['username','city','country'])
    ->whereIn('id', function($query) use($user) {
        $query->select('friend_id')
        ->from('friends')
        ->where('status', 'received')
        ->where('user_id', $user->id);
    })->get();
```